# MySQL on Mac OS X Issues

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I installed MySQL from:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html#macosx-dmg

I am on OS X 10.5.8.  I open Terminal and do:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

then:

```
mysql -u root
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have spent the last 2 hours scouring sites looking for an answer that makes sense.  This is a brand new laptop.  I am at a loss.  Here is my .bash_profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/blwatson/pythonpath;/Users/blwatson/pythonpath/bin:$PYTHONPATH

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export

PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

I am at a loss.  The install order was:

1) Django
2) Python 2.6
3) MySQL 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the socket exists at /tmp/mysql.sock. If not, start mysql

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
```

Then try logging into the mysql client

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

Comment: OK...so you now have me running.  First, thank you.  Second, what did you do exactly?  Third, will I have to run that mysqld_safe command every time?  I am a Windows guy and new to dev environment on Mac OS X.  Quick learner, but still learning.

Comment: In the DMG is a file called *MySql.prefPane*.  Run that and it will install a System Preferences pane that lets you control whether or not MySql starts on boot.

Comment: Wow...3 hours of frustration reduced to 6 lines of answers from ServerFault users.  Thanks guys.  Now I just have to sort out how to get PythonMySQL sorted.

Comment: I have found the mysql prefpane to be somewhat broken on 10.5, and I havn't even bothered with it on 10.6 (as it will be 32-bit). A better solution to autostart mysql is to create a launch daemon and submit it to launchd as described here:
http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080128103022907

Answer (score 1):

Did you start MySQL?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer that question.

Comment: Well, if you don't know if you started it, you probably didn't.

ps aux|grep mysql

if you didn't install the system preference pane off the DMG, do that, and use it to start MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

To start MySql go to System Preferences  > MySql > Start

Comment: I do not see MySql in the System Preferences

Comment: Because that option is added to the System Preference panel if you install the MySQL package from the official site.